# How to catch errors when using variable argument list in constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, argument-passing

I have a constructor that takes a variable argument list. It works fine. Except if someone enters the wrong number of arguments it goes berserk. How can I catch when they do this? Since the program is trusting the user to enter the correct number of variables, I'm not sure.

VecXd.hpp:

```
#ifndef JF_VecXd
#define JF_VecXd

#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

template <class T>
class VecXd{
    public: 
        VecXd(int num, ...);   
        void display();


        private:
            int size;
            T * elements;

};

template <class T> 
VecXd<T>::VecXd(int num, ...):size(num){
    va_list argP; 
    va_start(argP, num);
    elements = new T[size];
    for(int n = 0; n < size; n++)
        elements[n] = va_arg(argP,T);
    va_end(argP);
}

template <class T>
void VecXd<T>::display(){
    std::cout << "Vector size is " << size << "\n";
    for(int n = 0; n < size; n++)
        std::cout << "element " << n << ": " << elements[n] << "\n";
}  

#endif
```

vTest.cpp:

```
#include "vecxd.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    VecXd<int> v2(5,1,2,3,4,5);    // correct number of args
    VecXd<int> v1(8,1,2,3,4,5);    // incorrect number of args
                                  //I don't know how to catch this error


    std::cout << "Vector 1:" << std::endl; 
    v1.display();

    std::cout << "Vector 2:" << std::endl; 
    v2.display();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If there's a restriction on how arguments to enter, you probably shouldn't be using varargs.

Comment: What about accepting an argument of type `std::array` or `std::vector` instead?

Comment: It might also summon nasal demons if the arguments passed are not of type `int`. Undefined behaviour, that is. `va_arg` is inherently unsafe if your compiler doesn't provide additional checks (which are not mandated by the Standard). If your compiler supports C++11, you could use variadic templates. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, just use `std::vector` instead of your own vector class.

Comment: This was part of a programming assignment I was given and the method of entry was specified by the professor. 

If there is no work-around to this then I suppose I could mention that in a comment...

Comment: `<stdarg.h>` is a C header. Those have correspondent C++ headers (remove `.h` and prefix with a `c`). In this case, `<cstdarg>`.

Comment: "This was part of a programming assignment I was given" I feel sorry for you. Ellipsis and `va_arg` are unsafe, there's no portable way to change that (i.e. no portable way to check the number of passed arguments). They've been de-facto superseded by variadic templates in C++11 (and were not very popular before).